# PHP Pagination with MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pagination

I'm building my own CMS. I have an administration system made and I can insert posts in the database with it, showing posts isn't a problem, but I have no idea on how to do the pagination.

And this is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `status` != 'draft'
```

Comment: Please be more specific

Comment: Pro tip: `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` returns the number of rows your query without `LIMIT` would return

Comment: @andrew as of 2023, this functiuon is deprecated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build your query to have a `LIMIT`

**End SQL Result;**

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status != 'draft' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT <<offset>>, <<amount>>
```

For example;

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status != 'draft' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 10 #Fetch first 10
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status != 'draft' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10, 10 #Fetch next 10
```

Have a read of [`LIMIT`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx)

You will need to `ORDER BY` your primary key, as it's not "safe" to rely on the order MySQL gives without the `ORDER BY` clause, in terms of pagination (as you may get duplicate rows (on different pages))

#### To paginate with PHP

Something like this should suffice

```
// Get the first row's offset
$intTotalPerPage = 10;
$intPage = isset($_GET['page']) && ctype_digit($_GET['page']) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 0;
$intStart = ($intPage * $intTotalPerPage);

// mysqli connect
$objMysqli = new mysqli("...");

// get a pageful of rows
$strStatus = 'draft';
$strSqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status != ? ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT ?, ?";
$objStmt = $objMysqli->prepare($strSqlQuery);
$objStmt->bind_param('sii',  $strStatus, $intStart, $intTotalPerPage);
$arrData = $objStmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// get the page count
$strSqlQuery = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM posts WHERE status != ?";
$objStmt = $objMysqli->prepare($strSqlQuery);
$objStmt->bind_param('s',  $strStatus);
$intTotalRows = $objStmt->get_result()->fetch_row[0];

$intTotalPages = ceil($intTotalRows / $intTotalPerPage);

// Display the data
foreach ($arrData as $arrRow) {
    
}
// display pagination links
for ($i = 0; $i <= $intTotalPages; $i++) {
    echo "<a href='?page=" . $i . "'>[" . $i . "]</a>&bsp;";
}
```

As suggested in the comments it's good practice to use prepare statements, by [binding parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: that's a silly comment. "oh noes, I put pagination at the top of the page. now I can't put it at the bottom".

Comment: Why aren't you using a `?` placeholder for the `LIMIT`? It's really sketchy to be using string concatenation here.

Comment: @tadman I should have, but as quick example and OP not showing any real attempt him/her self, I didn't. I shall add a note to use prepared statements. Also why is sting concatenation sketchy?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑOne mistake with string concatenation and you have a [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/). If you're using placeholders it will take *several* mistakes before you have an issue, so there's considerably more safety. Your "quick example" actually promotes dangerously bad habits that can be hard to break. It's very little work to do it correctly, all it takes is `bind_param`, something that serves as a basis for extending it with dynamic `WHERE` conditions, for example.

Comment: LIMIT goes last http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html - Seen this from a question posted today that used this question to refer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/39229936/1415724 - the link you gave http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx also uses the right syntax `ORDER BY
 creditlimit DESC
LIMIT 5;`

Comment: `$objTotalRows = mysqli_query("SELECT` that is missing the connection for it - `$objTotalRows = mysqli_query($objDbLink, "SELECT` - I found this Q&A from a Google search looking for a possible duplicate.