# How to make a pagination system with PHP MySQLi Object-oriented

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

I tried searching for 4 days about making a pagination system, but I am unable to understand any code on the internet because i am newbie.

Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT name_id, name FROM TABLE WHERE tag1 in ('$tag1') OR tag2 in ('$tag1') $andor tag2 in ('$tag2') OR tag1 in ('$tag2') ORDER BY rating desc LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0";



$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Pagination html code:

```
   <div class='pagination'>
      <a>1</a>
   </div>
```

I don't know what to do. Can you please explain this code to me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Pagination with MySQLi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041382/php-pagination-with-mysqli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to count the number of records so you can calculate the number of pages.

```
$row_count = $con->query("SELECT count(name_id) FROM TABLE WHERE tag1 in ('$tag1') OR tag2 in ('$tag1') $andor tag2 in ('$tag2') OR tag1 in ('$tag2') ORDER BY rating desc LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0";");
```

now you can calculate the number of pages `$row_count/5` (5 in case you like to show 5 result each time)

then on the page you generate you'll need  to create a set of links which call the same page but with a different page number

```
<a href="/page.php?page=2>2<a>
<a href="/page.php?page=3>3<a>
...
```

then you need to use the `page` value as the offset for your query.

```
 $offset = 5*$_GET['page'];
 $sql = "SELECT name_id, name FROM TABLE WHERE tag1 in ('$tag1') OR tag2 in ('$tag1') $andor tag2 in ('$tag2') OR tag1 in ('$tag2') ORDER BY rating desc LIMIT 5 OFFSET $offset";
```

Comment: Well Explained, thanks a lot man!

Comment: Wait, their is nothing $con-query in my script. I am getting this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\db.php:48 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\db.php on line 48

Comment: I didn't write a valid php code, I just tried to give you a basic over view of how to implement what you are looking for. In the above case you'll need to put the query in a prepared statement and then call the query