# overide the existing data to new data from database after clicking on specific button

Tags: php

I have the main page in PHP and data is coming from database phpMyadmin database.I have limit in while loop to extract videos data from database.Limit is only 10 videos,i have placed a button below of the videos and i want when someone click on it, the next ten videos from database must shown and these ten videos must overide the previous videos on the same page.
I have tried a lot but could not succeed. I really need your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **pagination** system using **LIMIT** in MySQL query

```
SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 10 #Fetch first 10
SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10, 10 #Fetch next 10
```

Also, **handle the button URL** so that when you are on page 1 it should look like this

```
<a href = "website.com/index.php?page=2">Next</a>
```

You can use **PHP sessions** to handle pagination.

[Refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041382/php-pagination-with-mysqli)

Comment: this works fine and to work without loading the page many times, you can use the ajax. call an ajax function on button click and display the success of ajax in the required div

Comment: Thank you very much i have sold it :)